# AsyncStorage.getItem returns undefined(even with .then and .parse)

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm attempting to store data in AsyncStorage and load them back(obviously). The .setItem function works, and the notification pops up at the bottom of the iOS simulator when I call it. However, the .getItem function doesn't work, and when I console.log it, returns `undefined`. I have two functions to store and fetch the data:

```
    setData = (rawDataToStore, keyToStore) => {
        data_store = JSON.stringify(rawDataToStore);
        AsyncStorage.setItem(keyToStore, data_store, () => {
            console.warn('Stored data!')
        } )
    }

    getData = (keyToSearch) => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem(keyToSearch).then(storage => {
            parsed_data = JSON.parse(storage);
            return parsed_data
        }).catch(e => console.warn(e))
    }
```

I just tested the functions in my render():

to save the data:

```
this.setData({value: 1}, "test_data");
```

to load the data:

```
console.log(this.getData("test_data"));
```

The console.log just returns undefined.

I'm completely new to Asyncstorage, but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: your `getData` function has no return (the one in .then callback doesn't count)

Comment: once you `return AsyncStorage.getItem.....` your next question will be "why is it returning a Promise" - because that's what `AsyncStorage.getItem` returns, a Promise

Comment: @Robert as per the post you linked, arrow functions with blocks require an explicit return. `getData` will return `undefined`.

Comment: @Robert - you're wrong, look at [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body)

Answer (score 0):

Your `console.log` returns `undefined` ... cause, your `setData` function hasn't finished its job yet ... you have to `await` for it first, cause it's an async operation.

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.setData();
    const data = await this.getData();

    console.log('data returned', data);
  }

  setData = async (rawDataToStore, keyToStore) => {
    data_store = JSON.stringify(rawDataToStore);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(keyToStore, data_store);
  };

  getData = async keyToSearch => {
    let parsed_data = null;

    const storage = await AsyncStorage.getItem(keyToSearch);
    if (storage) {
      parsed_data = JSON.parse(storage);
      console.log('Data in AsyncStorage: ', parsed_data);
    }

    return parsed_data;
  };
}
```